# Deleting any user from material table resets the page number

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

My list is getting updated from the server and pagination up to 10 items per page are set.
Scenario (Problem)- When I am on any page let's say on the 4th page ( other than 1 ) and I delete an item from the list on that page when the list updates this deletion the table is rendered from page 1. I want the page to auto-reload on the 4th page only.

Comment: We can't help you if we don't know the details. Is the API paginated, how are you requesting the data and showing this? Are you paginating client-side? If the API is paginated you should be able to re-request items 31-40 after the delete. Worse case scenario is you request the 5th page and take the first item and append to a client-side copy of the 9 remaining items and show these 10.

Comment: Could you share me more detail to give the solution for your problem.